# Scroll QML Grid

Tags: qt, grid, scroll, qml

I want to make my QML `Grid` scrollable as soon as the content is too long for it to display.

```
Grid {
     objectName: "sidebarView"
     id: sidebarGrid
     flow: Grid.TopToBottom
     columns: 1
     spacing: 10
}
```

Is that possible with just a few properties added to the `Grid`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, but you can just put a Flickable around the Grid

```
Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight: sidebarGrid.height
    contentWidth: sidebarGrid.width

    Grid {
         objectName: "sidebarView"
         id: sidebarGrid
         flow: Grid.TopToBottom
         columns: 1
         spacing: 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information, flickable can wrap most of the things that goes out of screen. Text, image can also be made flickable.